# div class(index.php) does not see css folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I want to access the class flags css inside the style.css file by doing div class = flags inside index.php. I did not get a result when I wrote the codes as below. the pictures look lower altitude. I want to make the pictures side by side.

index.php

```
<div class="flags">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="?dil=tr"><img src="http://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flags/flags/32/German.png" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="?dil=en"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flags/flags/32/England.png" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.flags {
  width: 100px;
  height: 320px;
  float: right;
}
.flags ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.flags ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: how are you accessing the `style.css` file? I mean the path

Comment: I wrote this now, but it has not improved. <link href = "css / style.css" rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text / css'

Comment: Did you remove the space from path e.g css / style.css will be css/style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would be the spacing in the `href`, that would be:

`<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

instead of

`<link href = "css / style.css" rel = 'stylesheet' type = 'text / css'>`

`css / style.css` is very different from `css/style.css`, it is like you are saying that the folder name has a space after it, and the file name has a space before it.

You will be adding it in:

```
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add these lines in your index.php page

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
```

And please note that the Path mentioned is valid one.

Comment: I understand, but where do I add it.

Comment: add it in the `<head>` tag. Just before you close `</head>`

Answer (score 0):

use the code below instead of .flags ul li

```
.flags ul li {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float:left;
}
```

The float property specifies how an element should float.